# How to sum data from multiple rows and columns according to unique variable in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to sum the average total sales of each employee in [this data frame](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m7HkVC8VB1IQ8vPoZB98_f6Nd75-Fv3KP32Ohp5QYVY/edit?usp=sharing) (sorry for format, i'm not sure how else to get a .csv uploaded here). For example, Tim sold ten vehicles day 1, nine day 2, and eleven day 3, for an average of 10 per day. Is there a way to grab all of the columns each time the employee's name shows up, then sum and average the total sales?

Comment: Question is a bit confusing. An example would definitely have gone a long way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dat <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Employee,    ~Day,   ~Car_Sales, ~Van_Sales, ~Truck_Sales,
"Tim",  "1/1",  5,  2,  3,
"Tim",  "1/2",  4,  2,  3,
"Tim",  "1/3",  7,  1,  3,
"Craig", "1/1", 2,  6,  1,
"Craig", "1/2", 5,  7,  2,
"Samantha", "1/1",  4,  3,  2)

dat %>% mutate(sales = Car_Sales + Van_Sales + Truck_Sales) %>% group_by(Employee) %>% summarise(Avg = mean(sales))
```

Output should look like this:

| Employee | Avg |
| --- | --- |
| Craig | 11.5 |
| Samantha | 9.0 |
| Tim | 10.0 |

I hope this is what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```r
library(dplyr)
dat <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Employee,    ~Day,   ~Car_Sales, ~Van_Sales, ~Truck_Sales,
"Tim",  "1/1",  5,  2,  3,
"Tim",  "1/2",  4,  2,  3,
"Tim",  "1/3",  7,  1,  3,
"Craig", "1/1", 2,  6,  1,
"Craig", "1/2", 5,  7,  2,
"Samantha", "1/1",  4,  3,  2)


dat %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(total_sales = sum(c_across(-c(1,2)))) %>% 
  group_by(Employee) %>% 
  summarise(average = mean(total_sales))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   Employee average
#>   <chr>      <dbl>
#> 1 Craig       11.5
#> 2 Samantha     9  
#> 3 Tim         10
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to put into a long format, then get the mean by summing all the data and divide by the number of days (i.e., using `n_distinct`).

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(ends_with("Sales")) %>%
  group_by(Employee) %>%
  summarise(Avg = sum(value) / n_distinct(Day))
```

**Output**

```
  Employee   Avg
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 Craig     11.5
2 Samantha   9  
3 Tim       10
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Employee = c("Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Craig", "Craig", 
"Samantha"), Day = c("1/1", "1/2", "1/3", "1/1", "1/2", "1/1"
), Car_Sales = c(5, 4, 7, 2, 5, 4), Van_Sales = c(2, 2, 1, 6, 
7, 3), Truck_Sales = c(3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```